# SQL statement not returning results after EXEC statement failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have my SQL script as follows

```
DECLARE @batch_load_key INT;

SELECT  @batch_load_key=batch_load_key
FROM load.batch_load
WHERE batch_load_name = N'xxxx';




UPDATE load.batch_load_partition_control SET is_batch_load_partition_processed = 0
WHERE batch_load_control_key IN
(
SELECT batch_load_control_key
FROM load.batch_load_control
WHERE batch_load_key = @batch_load_key
);



UPDATE load.batch_load_control SET is_batch_load_processed = 0
WHERE batch_load_key = @batch_load_key;


SELECT  @batch_load_key=batch_load_key
FROM load.batch_load
WHERE batch_load_name = N'xxxx';

DECLARE @batch_load_control_code NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT @batch_load_control_code = batch_load_control_code
FROM load.batch_load_control
WHERE batch_load_key = @batch_load_key;



EXEC base.usp_load_fact_table @batch_load_control_code=@batch_load_control_code,@disable_output=1;

SELECT * from
load.batch_load_partition_control WHERE batch_load_control_key IN
(
SELECT batch_load_control_key
FROM load.batch_load_control
WHERE batch_load_key in (SELECT batch_load_key
FROM load.batch_load
WHERE batch_load_name = N'xxxx')
) AND is_batch_load_partition_processed = 1;
```

My EXEC step is expected to fail due to a PK violation scenario I am testing. The following select statement will tell me if my scenario has failed as per the expectations. But my results window does not show the result from select after getting the failure of EXEC step. Can you please guide on how I can get the select to return rows? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your only `SELECT` statement in that batch that returns a result set is *after* your `EXEC` statement. Very likely your batch is therefore aborted when the `EXEC` fails and thus the `SELECT` statement isn't run.

Comment: Have you looked at *try/catch*?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the point. Yes, that's precisely what is happening.

Comment: @Stu Thank you for the guidance. The try/catch block addition was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Stu suggested, I tried adding the try/catch block and it worked for my scenario.

```
BEGIN TRY
EXEC base.usp_load_fact_table @batch_load_control_code=@batch_load_control_code,@disable_output=1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT * from
load.batch_load_partition_control WHERE batch_load_control_key IN
(
SELECT batch_load_control_key
FROM load.batch_load_control
WHERE batch_load_key in (SELECT batch_load_key
FROM load.batch_load
WHERE batch_load_name = N'xxxx')
) AND is_batch_load_partition_processed = 1;
END CATCH
```